# Carregar um campo TEXTAREA a partir de um SELECT com Jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

Tenho um modal que realiza envio de e-mail. Só que eu criei alguns modelos de email no banco de dados **mysql**. Na tela aparece o meu select com todos os modelos para seleção, só que eu gostaria de quando for selecionado o modelo, ele preenchesse o **input** "*assunto*" e o **textarea** "*conteudo*" com as informações vindo do banco de dados.

Abaixo segue o meu **HTML** com select usando **PHP**:

```html
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="form-control-label">Assunto:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control limpar" id="assunto">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="form-control-label">Modelo:</label>
    <select class="form-control m-input limpar" id="select_acao" name="id_atividade_tipo">
      <option>Selecione</option>
      <?php
                      $sql_modelo = $db->prepare("SELECT * from modelo_email");          
                      $sql_modelo->execute();   $atv = 0  ;        
                                      while($row_modelo=$sql_modelo->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC)){
                                        $atv++; ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_modelo['id']?>">
          <?php echo utf8_encode($row_modelo['nome'])?>
        </option>
        <?php }?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">

  <textarea class="summernote" id="conteudo" name="conteudo">
                <br/> 
                 </textarea>
</div>
```

Acredito que esse processo deva ser feito com **jquery** e **Ajax** fazendo requisição em uma página **PHP**, mas não sei como faria dessa forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você disse, tem que chamar um Ajax para uma página PHP e retornar o *assunto* e o *conteúdo*. Você pode retornar um JSON do PHP com esses dois valores e quando o Ajax for completado, inserir cada valor no seu campo.

Primeira coisa é colocar um `onchange` no `select` para chamar uma função que irá processar o Ajax. Coloque no `select`:

```
onchange="carrega()"
```

E insira a função no script:

```
function carrega(){

   $("#select_acao").prop("disabled", true); // desabilita o select

   $.ajax({
      url:'pagina.php',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'id='+ $("#select_acao").val(), // envia o valor do select
      success: function(data){
         data = JSON.parse(data);
         $("#assunto").val(data.assunto); // insere o assunto no input
         var conteudo = data.conteudo.replace(/\/n/g, '\n'); // restaura a quebra de linha
         $("#conteudo").val(conteudo); // insere o conteúdo do email no textarea
      },
      complete: function(){
         $("#select_acao").prop("disabled", false); // reabilita o select
      }
   });
}
```

No exemplo acima o Ajax chama um PHP `pagina.php`, mas você pode usar outro nome que quiser.

Na página PHP você deve retornar um JSON com duas chaves: `assunto` e `conteudo`, neste formato, fazendo um `echo`:

```
echo json_encode('{"assunto": "'.$assunto.'", "conteudo": "'.$conteudo.'"}');
```

As variáveis `$assunto` e `$conteudo` você irá puxar do banco de dados de acordo com o `id` recebido com `$_POST['id']` que foi enviado pelo Ajax.

**Problema:** A variável `$assunto` é uma linha só, não tem problema. O problema é com o conteúdo do email que vai na variável `$conteudo` que pode ter quebras de linha, e isso tonará o JSON inválido.

Para resolver você deve eliminar as quebras de linha com `str_replace` antes do `echo`. Minha sugestão é inverter a barra do `\n`:

```
$conteudo = str_replace("\n", "/n", $conteudo);
```

O PHP ficará algo assim:

```
<?php
// consulta o banco de dados de acordo com o valor em $_POST['id']
$assunto = valor da coluna "assunto" do banco;
$conteudo = valor da coluna "conteudo" do banco;

$conteudo = str_replace("\n", "/n", $conteudo); // elimina as quebras de linha
echo json_encode('{"assunto": "'.$assunto.'", "conteudo": "'.$conteudo.'"}');
?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado DVD